# Auto Layout on Series of Labels for Different Screen Sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

this is my first "App Store" app that I want to make and I know auto layout is crucial in getting an app on the app store.

This is what my page looks like:
[image]

Basically it is a series of Labels and I will have a button too. Some of the labels change based on the result of the game.

What I am wondering is what is the best way to set this design so it looks similar on all devices? View cells? Code? Both?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design fits in a tableview, simply wrap all your labels in tableview cells and sections with autolayout stretching in all directions of the cell and section view. And put the button and the last label in a footer. This will work for you